# Issue in migrating Jboss 5.0 to 7.1

Tags: javascript, java, jboss7.x, jdk1.7

I have an issue in my web application. Recently we started migrating the code from JDK 1.6 to 1.7 and the JBOSS from 5.0.1 to 7.1. The local set up is done. I had changed the compiler version, adding jars to the build path, changing the standalone.xml is also done.. The application is booting up but there is a problem with the @XMLrootelement defined in the VO objects of the class. We generally use this XML root element to process all the response coming out from the AJAX call used in the application. Now the root element from the Ajax is missing from the reponse. I got some of the warnings during my server start up.. 
Please help how to proceed further.

SERVER LOGS

18:34:58,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "pce_service.war"

18:34:58,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "pw_pgp_pce.war"

18:34:58,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "pci_service.war"

18:35:01,346 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pw_pgp_pce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:01,346 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pw_pgp_pce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:01,347 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pw_pgp_pce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:01,503 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pw_pgp_pce.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:02,862 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pce_service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:02,862 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pce_service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:02,863 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pce_service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:02,863 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/C:/Users/mp831402/Downloads/All PCE related files/AWS workspace/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/pce_service.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

18:35:04,985 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2

18:35:04,985 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2

Comment: As I suspected, JBoss was confused and was still partially using the old RESTeasy version. The solution is to upgrade RESTeasy in JBoss, according to RESTeasy documentation:

3.1. Upgrading Resteasy Within JBoss AS 7

Resteasy is bundled with JBoss AS 7. You will likely have the need to upgrade Resteasy in AS7. The Resteasy distribution comes with a zip file called resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.5.Final.zip. Unzip this file while with the modules/ directory of the JBoss AS7 distribution. This will overwrite some of the existing files there.